# mod rewrite with fixed string between two dynamics

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got an URL like this:

```
filter.php?gender=male&fid=1&sid=x
```

and I want to use `mod_rewrite` to rewrite it like this:

```
/Male/Apparel/Jackets
```

as an example...

I already tried the following but itonly puts the first var (male) to the query string and skips the second one (example: jackets)

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/Apparel/^([a-zA-Z]+) filter.php?gender=$1&fid=1&sid=$2
```

I also tried the following syntax without success:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/Apparel/([a-zA-Z]+) filter.php?gender=$1&fid=1&sid=$2
```

What have I done wrong? Isn't it possible to put an exact string between two dynamic string or did I just use a wrong syntax?

Comment: Your second syntax seems OK, what exactly happens if you try that?